# Multiple Validation Rule

Tags: validation, list-validation

I have the following validation rule that works perfectly which makes mandatory `[Customer]` and `[Member]` columns if column `[Feedback Type]` equals "Ticket" from a drop down list:

```
=IF([Feedback Type]="Ticket",AND([Customer]<>"",AND([Member]<>"")),TRUE)
```

I need further validation rule but have no idea if it is possible to build further validations; what I also need is:

If `[Feedback Type]` equals **"Ticket" or "Customer"** from a drop down list then `[Customer]` and `[Member]` must be mandatory.

Ideally I would like also the following validation rule included:

If the column `[Feedback Type]` equals "Colleague" from a drop down list then `[Colleague]` must be mandatory but not `[Customer]` and `[Member]`

Hope the above makes sense!

Thanks

Comment: Is "Colleague" a people or group field?

Comment: Colleague is a people picker column

Comment: You cannot use people picker in any formulae

Answer (score 0):

Try using below formula:

```
=IF([Feedback Type]="Colleague", IF(ISBLANK([Colleague]), false, true), IF(OR([Feedback Type]="Ticket",[Feedback Type]="Customer"), IF(OR(ISBLANK([Customer]),ISBLANK([Member])), false, true), true))
```

**References**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [Examples of common formulas in SharePoint Lists](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3).

Comment: Thanks but it seems to have an error...

Comment: Are you getting error while saving the column formula? Or getting incorrect results while saving items?